# Python Regex - selectively naming groups by using '|' ('or' in regex)

Tags: python, regex

I am using python regex to match patterns with strings and faced a problem with naming groups based on several templates.

When simplified it will be a problem with writing;

```
pattern = r'(?P<one>1)|(?P<one>one)'
string = 'one'
re.match(pattern, string).groupdict()
```

I want to have `{'one': 1}` or `{'one': 'one'}` as an output.
However, this raises the error;

```
error: redefinition of group name 'one' as group 2; was group 1 at position 15
```

---

A more concrete example:
I have a list of strings, each string containing;

- prefix like 'hello'
- the person's gender, and
- his/her birthday

like this;

```
['hello F 10/Feb', 'hello Jan/12 M', 'hi F Feb 15', ...]
```

and so on.

They seemed to have a diversity but all of them follow one of the templates;

- prefix + [space] + gender + [space] + day + '/' + month
- prefix + [space] + month + '/' + day + [space] + gender
- prefix + [space] + gender + [space] + month + [space] + day

so I thought of using a regex and contain them into a dictionary by using `re.match()`.

As a start I made a list of templates written in regex.

```
template = [
r'((?P<gender>[FM]) (?P<day>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+))',
r'((?P<month>.+)/(?P<month>\d+) (?P<gender>[FM]))',
r'((?P<gender>[FM]) (?P<month>.+)/(?P<day>\d))',]
```

Here, I removed the greetings part since it never changes it's position and because I wanted to keep the prefix part as a variable `prefix` for usability purposes.

Then I tried to join them with a `'|'` like this

```
prefix + r'|'.join(template)
```

to make the regex form in one connected string.

However, when I tried to match it with regex, I had the error for redifinition.

---

I know that it could be done by

```
for i in template:
    re.match(prefix + i, string)
```

kind of thing, but if possible, I want to keep the pattern string in one line.

Is this possible?

(I use Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit))

Comment: This is possible in some regex engines that support branch reset groups (e.g. PCRE), but sadly not in `re`. Should be supported by the PyPi regex module according to doc. Syntax would then be `(?|(?P<one>1)|(?P<one>one))`.

Comment: thanks a lot!
By the way, is there any reason that the default re module does not support this way of writing ? or is it just not proposed.

Comment: It is not supported by the re module. I don't know why devs chose to implement the module in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not with the standard re module.
The feature you are looking for is a branch reset group, that allows to redefine groups for different alternations. This can be used for numbered groups as well as for named groups. To use it in python you can use the [PyPi Regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

General Syntax is `(?|(.)|(.))` where both capturing groups are numbered with 1, as they occur in different alternations. The same can be used for named groups, so your example could be writte as `(?|(?P<one>1)|(?P<one>one))`.

See the [demo on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Gn8RfM/1).

Note: This is using a PCRE pattern, there are differences between PCRE and the regex module, but the features shown are shared by both.